# Example or Code or Sample and scenarios of provider hosted app and SharePoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Can someone give me example of provider hosted app and SharePoint hosted app.
A working code / Project will be very helpful

Also can someone give me realtime scenarios (not a theory but live requirement) when and where we use these apps

Answer (score 0):

I got a lot out of performing the Lab steps from these 2 course materials on GitHub.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/tree/master/O3652-5%20Deep%20Dive%20into%20SharePoint%20Hosted%20Apps

https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/tree/master/O3652-6%20Deep%20Dive%20into%20Provider%20Hosted%20Apps

The corresponding courses were excellent but are apparently not still stored out on the web! :-(

Also your second question is very broad, so I cannot give a good reference for this.

Regards..Antelope

Comment: I have been having same query came accross this the above links are broken. do you have some other source to this @antelope